# How can I match within a MIME header substring using Regex, matching the last occurrence of a closing string to an opening string

Tags: javascript, regex, mime

I have a string that I'm trying to extract information from…

```
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?=A1=F1?= text =?iso-8859-1?B?KJLHDHmnflkjheJKLJVC=?=
```

I want my regex to extract…

`=?iso-8859-1?Q?=A1=F1?=` and `=?iso-8859-1?B?KJLHDHmnflkjheJKLJVC=?=`

**The Regex I have at the moment…**

I've written the following Regex - which is nearly, but not quite, right…

```
=\?(.*?)\?=
```

**The problem**

The problem is that this extracts the following…

`=?iso-8859-1?Q?=` and `=?iso-8859-1?B?KJLHDHmnflkjheJKLJVC=?=`

As you can see, the Regex is confused by the `?=` following Q - despite the fact that this is not the last occurrence of this string after the initial opening `=?`.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: Use `=\?(.*?)\?=(?!\S)`

Comment: If this wasn't closed then you'd get a correct answer for this.  Thank you so much!

Comment: These "word" boundary type question are too frequent, no need for another answer.